# Docker jenkins container is stuck while running

Tags: docker, jenkins

I can't run a jenkins image with docker.
It is getting stuck while running:

> afik@ubuntu:~$ docker run --name myjenkins -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /var/jenkins_home jenkins > out1 Aug 23, 2018 10:34:41 AM Main deleteWinstoneTempContents WARNING: Failed to delete the temporary Winstone file /tmp/winstone/jenkins.war Aug 23, 2018 10:34:41 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info INFO: Logging initialized @422ms Aug 23, 2018 10:34:41 AM winstone.Logger logInternal INFO: Beginning extraction from war file Aug 23, 2018 10:34:42 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog warn WARNING: Empty contextPath Aug 23, 2018 10:34:42 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info INFO: jetty-9.2.z-SNAPSHOT Aug 23, 2018 10:34:42 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info INFO: NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet Aug 23, 2018 10:34:43 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info INFO: Started w.@47404bea{/,file:/var/jenkins_home/war/,AVAILABLE}{/var/jenkins_home/war} Aug 23, 2018 10:34:43 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info INFO: Started ServerConnector@1252b961{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080} Aug 23, 2018 10:34:43 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info INFO: Started @2442ms Aug 23, 2018 10:34:43 AM winstone.Logger logInternal INFO: Winstone Servlet Engine v2.0 running: controlPort=disabled Aug 23, 2018 10:34:43 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained INFO: Started initialization Aug 23, 2018 10:34:43 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained INFO: Listed all plugins Aug 23, 2018 10:34:44 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained INFO: Prepared all plugins Aug 23, 2018 10:34:44 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained INFO: Started all plugins Aug 23, 2018 10:34:44 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained INFO: Augmented all extensions Aug 23, 2018 10:34:44 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained INFO: Loaded all jobs Aug 23, 2018 10:34:45 AM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run INFO: Started Download metadata Aug 23, 2018 10:34:45 AM jenkins.util.groovy.GroovyHookScript execute INFO: Executing /var/jenkins_home/init.groovy.d/tcp-slave-agent-port.groovy Aug 23, 2018 10:34:45 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained INFO: Completed initialization Aug 23, 2018 10:34:45 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@7147f78f: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Thu Aug 23 10:34:45 UTC 2018]; root of context hierarchy Aug 23, 2018 10:34:45 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory INFO: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@7147f78f]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@6dbf29b1 Aug 23, 2018 10:34:45 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@6dbf29b1: defining beans [authenticationManager]; root of factory hierarchy Aug 23, 2018 10:34:45 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@74caac54: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Thu Aug 23 10:34:45 UTC 2018]; root of context hierarchy Aug 23, 2018 10:34:45 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory INFO: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@74caac54]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@4e956477 Aug 23, 2018 10:34:45 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@4e956477: defining beans [filter,legacy]; root of factory hierarchy Aug 23, 2018 10:34:45 AM jenkins.install.SetupWizard init INFO: ************************************************************* ************************************************************* ************************************************************* Jenkins initial setup is required. An admin user has been created and a password generated. Please use the following password to proceed to installation: ac6f4e5afd7c4a7f8ee2d360b3c5649d This may also be found at: /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword ************************************************************* ************************************************************* ************************************************************* Aug 23, 2018 10:34:50 AM hudson.model.UpdateSite updateData INFO: Obtained the latest update center data file for UpdateSource default Aug 23, 2018 10:34:51 AM hudson.WebAppMain$3 run INFO: Jenkins is fully up and running Aug 23, 2018 10:34:51 AM hudson.model.UpdateSite updateData INFO: Obtained the latest update center data file for UpdateSource default Aug 23, 2018 10:34:53 AM hudson.model.DownloadService$Downloadable load INFO: Obtained the updated data file for hudson.tasks.Maven.MavenInstaller Aug 23, 2018 10:34:54 AM hudson.model.DownloadService$Downloadable load INFO: Obtained the updated data file for hudson.tools.JDKInstaller Aug 23, 2018 10:34:54 AM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run INFO: Finished Download metadata. 9,318 ms ^CAug 23, 2018 10:36:00 AM winstone.Logger logInternal INFO: JVM is terminating. Shutting down Winstone afik@ubuntu:~$

Answer (score 2):

You actually are running Jenkins... you're just doing it "interactively." That is, you're attached to the process that the `docker run` command kicked off. If you look at the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/587b2856cd225bb152c4abeeaaa24934c75aa460/Dockerfile#L70) for the Jenkins image, you'll see:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/tini", "--", "/usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh"]
```

This basically says that, when you `run` a Jenkins container, it will kick off that shell script. When you get to the point of seeing this:

```
INFO: Finished Download metadata. 9,318 ms
```

You're Jenkins container is up and running. You should be able to open a browser and point it to `http://localhost:8080/`, where you should see the Jenkins UI.

In order to *not* have your terminal window sit on the command like that, you need to instruct docker to **detach** from the container (sort of like running a process in the background). If you run `docker run --help`, you'll see the following entry:

```
-d, --detach        Run container in background and print container ID
```

So you just need to use the `-d` flag in your command:

```
docker run --name myjenkins -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /var/jenkins_home -d jenkins
```

Instead of showing you the logs, it will instead display a container ID (a big long alphanumeric). Now, if you want to see the logs (for instance, to get the Jenkins-generated password), you can use:

```
docker logs myjenkins
```

(that's the name you assigned to the container with the `--name` option) or

```
docker logs [container ID]
```